# How to correct misformatted URLs in input

Tags: url, low-replace

I'm trying to use Low Replace to correct URLs in a standard text field in EE.

Sometimes the URL is inputted correctly, for example http://www.a-website.com other times they are inputted incorrectly ie www.another-website.com

I think I nearly have the solution, but the colon after http isn't being rendered on the page, so the corrected URL for the above example comes out as http//www.another-website.com. Please see my code below.

```
{exp:low_replace find="www." replace="http://www."}
    <p><a href="{website}" target="_blank">Website</a></p>
{/exp:low_replace}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people doesn't know, but EllisLab has a first party [add-on](https://github.com/EllisLab/Valid-Url) for that:

```
<p><a href="{exp:valid_url}{website}{/exp:valid_url}" target="_blank">Website</a></p>
```

There's several first party [add-ons available for download](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/#available-for-download), despite not included on EECMS by default.